# Convert variable of type double to date and time

Tags: date, time, double, stata

How do I do the following in Stata:

I have a variable of type double with values similar to the ones below:

```
20180405013331
20160107085521
```

How can I convert it to a date/time (YYYYMMDDhhmmss) variable like the following:

```
2018April5 01:33:31
2016January7 08:55:21
```

Answer (score 1):

`help datetime` explains the basics here. The only extra twist is that your date-times arrive as a `double`, so you need to convert to a string, which can be done on the fly.

```
clear 
input double mydate 
20180405013331
20160107085521
end 

format mydate %14.0f 

gen double wanted = clock(string(mydate, "%14.0f"), "YMDhms") 
format wanted %tc 

list 

     +-------------------------------------+
     |         mydate               wanted |
     |-------------------------------------|
  1. | 20180405013331   05apr2018 01:33:31 |
  2. | 20160107085521   07jan2016 08:55:21 |
     +-------------------------------------+
```